# making excel chart ignore bad data

Tags: excel, linechart

I'm trying to make a chart in Excel that plots thousands of data points. My problem is that some of these data points are bad and should be ignored in the chart. My data is currently formatted like the following (but could be changed if necessary), where each new line is a new row:

```
*-1.0
*-1.0
*-1.0
*86.25
*89.94
94.22
96.80
*92.56
95.29
96.38
*91.24
94.67
95.22
```

and so on. Any data points with a * before it is bad data that should be ignored. Ideally, I am looking for a way to pretend these points don't exist and to chart the remaining values as if they were arranged like so:

```
94.22
96.80
95.29
96.38
94.67
95.22
```

I've tried making a chart with every data point, but all data points with a * act like zeroes instead of not existing. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Hide the rows with bad data points? Hidden rows aren't graphed.

Comment: @BigBen is there a way to automatically hide these rows? It's not exactly viable to do this by hand as there are many thousands of data points

Comment: You could use VBA to do this.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this? I'm not familiar with VBA

Answer (score 0):

Create another column, do (assuming the data is in Column A):

```
=if(left(A1)="*","",A1) in B1
```

and drag downwards.. then use Data > filter in column B. Do new table from the fresh data.

Hope it helps. ( :